# Getting Started w/ Blockchain & Your Website

Tags: blockchain, javascript, nft

What’s up everybody! Just a normal developer who’s done his fair share of online websites and business but I’m very interested in creating and NFT marketplace to host my NFT project… I want it to operate like OpenSea but just for my collection but unlike OpenSea…

//// ANSWERS NEEDED ////

I don’t know how to:

1. How to connect to the Blockchain
2. How to make each image special and connect to the blockchain
3. Keep track off all the movements of the NFT on the blockchain to show user price and how many times it changed hands
4. How to test all this in a beta version
5. How to manipulate the smart contract in the way that there is royalties involved
6. How does whitelisting work in the fact of the coding… I understand the concept of the first come first serve but how does all that translate to the code
7. How do I go about the backend after I set up the frontend

**CODING IN JAVASCRIPT & REACT**

Comment: Would you like the answers to go along with a complementary $100.000 as well?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well that's a lot of broad questions and you will need to do some learning on your own. At this point I think I can only provide you with resources.

I think with Scaffold Eth: https://docs.scaffoldeth.io/scaffold-eth/ you can get started the quickest, and it's completely hands on.

There's also an NFT tutorial in there, among the others.